# Can i capture CLI (console) logs of Cisco device using python

Tags: python, logging, command-line-interface, cisco

I am looking for python script so i can get CLI log messages of my Cisco switch to my file so i can display it later to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways you can process logging information from a Cisco switch using Python.

For example, you can have the logging data sent to a SYSLOG server and from python open the log file created by the SYSLOG server and read it with Python.

Another way would be to have Python login to the switch.  You can use a module like Paramiko or PEXPECT to login into the switch.  From there while logged in, write the information collected into a file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what if i want to capture console log (messages) of cisco device. ....Like if i telnet through python and send "terminal monitor"... maybe the interface goes down and message appears, i want it to be immediately write on my file through python program.... kinda of live logs writing to my file/or showing on webpage through python script

Comment: What i would normally do would be to send the console logging information as a SYSLOG to a SYSLOG server.  Then from the SYSLOG server, it would be configured to write to a file.  Let's call the file syslog.txt.  From for example a Linux system, I would have a command "tail -f ./syslog.txt" that would continuously display the logging information.  It I want to monitor an interface i would use a command like "tail -f ./syslog.txt | egrep "<interface_id>" and it will display that interface anytime it encounters it.

With windows, use powershell's get-content to do the same.

HTH, 
rickr

Comment: Really appreciate your quick response, is this possible to do it without using syslog,actually i don't want to use syslog configuration in my switch.....will appreciate if you can share any idea

Comment: If you don't want another application running on the network, then logging information would need to be captured from the console itself.  for that to happen, you will need python to login the switch with Paramiko/EXPECT, or... and collect the output to a file.  Aside from these two modules, there's other framework like Ansible or YANG that might serve what you are looking for.  However, that would also go through the process of taking a "show logging" output and redirected to some sort of process..  Cisco IOS-XE 16.3.x  has python built into it.  Something to try -- HTH, rickr

Answer (score 0):

Use telentlib or paramiko and save the output in text file.

Example:

```
import paramiko

HOST='X.X.X.V'
PORT='22'
USER = 'Username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

def CaptureLogs():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("sh version")
    output= (stdout.readlines())
    capture=open('capture.txt','w')
    capture.write(output)
    capture.close()
    client.close()

CaptureLogs()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what if i want to capture console log (messages) of cisco device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what if i want to capture console log (messages) of cisco device. ....Like if i telnet through python and send "terminal monitor"... maybe the interface goes down and message appears, i want it to be immediately write on my file through python program.... kinda of live logs writing to my file/or showing on webpage through python script